# Orchard CMS, Merging templates

Tags: orchardcms

I am developing a Widget to show Content pushes on the home page. The push model is as below.

public class PushRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual string Header { get; set; }
        public virtual string Text { get; set; }
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    }

On the admin, I modified the ContentType of the Push Widget to add Media Picker Field. I would like to make a hyper link around the image with Url provided by PushPart. Npw the widget is rendered by two templates, Parts.Push.cshtml and Fields.MediaPicker-PushWidget-Image.cshtml. How do I merge these two and make my Push rendering possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to merge them? You did not say what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try suppressing display of mediapickerfield via placement.info, and then explicitly render the image with the hyperlink from the .cshtml of the PushPart. You can access the MediaPickerField url like this:

```
@{ 
    var pushPart = Model.ContentPart;
    var photoUrl = pushPart.MediaPickerFieldName.Url;
}
<a href="@GetYourUrlFromPushPart"><img src="@photoUrl" ... /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried a lot around this, I am getting an exception Models.PushPart' does not contain a definition for 'MediaPickerFieldName'. I guess I am missing something.

Comment: Can you paste the code for the view where you get this error?

Comment: I added the MediaPickerField from the admin panel by modifying PushWideget. When I added in the migration.cs, it is working as expected.Thanks for your help